# Modify/Change the CSR for view page for a POST in a Blog Site

Tags: view, blog, jslink, client-side-rendering

I am working on CSR to add a button and change the look and feel of like and comment button for a Blog Site. Currently I am able to achieve this, and it is functional(Button).

[image: CSR preview for custom UI]

I am using the below (JSLink) code to achieve it.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = { 'Body':{'View': CBody} };

    console.log("Registering CSR");
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})(); 

function CBody(ctx) {
    var ret = ctx.CurrentItem.Body + "<b>" + 
"<button onclick='myfunc(ctx);' type='button' >Report Abuse</button>" + "</b><hr/>" ;
    return ret;
}
```

Now I should make it look like this.

[image: Desired View]

is there a way that i can append a button after the Comment button of Image 1, after that manipulating css will be easier.

I tried to override like below,

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = { 'PostCategory':{'View': CDate} };

function CDate(ctx) {
    var ret =  "<br> <b>" + 
"<button onclick='func(ctx);' type='button' >One More Test</button>" + "</b><hr/>" ;
    return ret;
}
```

But for my luck it didn't worked at all.
what field should I override in my case. CSR is under documented for SharePoint please suggest me which field/Tag/View/Whatever is need to overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command bar/links such as Like, Comment etc are outside the Body section of the blog. You can see the rendered HTML in firebug/IE developer tools.

Instead of overring the Body field, create a PostRenderHandler for your view and then it's all about injecting your extra HTML mark up at the correct element.

```
overrideContext.OnPostRender = your_function_here();
```

Within your postRender function, add something like this:

```
var ulDD = $("ul.ms-comm-forumCmdList li:last-child");
ulDD.before("<li id='liButton1' class='ms-comm-cmdSpaceListItem'><span><a class='myBtn' href='#'>Share</a></span></li><li id='liButton2' class='ms-comm-cmdSpaceListItem'><span><a class='myBtn' href='#'>Report</a></span></li>");
```

that would result as:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Aveenav for giving the suggestion, I am sure this will work for me.